# Can't insert a breakpoint into shader when debug on vs with Nsight

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, glsl, shader, nsight

[image]I already choose a drawcall in scrubber view,and vs said A breakpoint could not be inserted at this location when i click.

Here is my configuration:

VS2017
GLSL3.3
Nsight5.6
GTX 1070Ti

Comment: Are you sure you can insert breakpoints in shader code like that? From what I just read Nsight offers the possiility of having breakpoints in CUDA and even then it's a bit different from linear code.

Answer (score 1):

Finally,I understand that the reason is that Nsight not support the architecture of my graphic card.So sad.